# Pyspark dataframe join elements as variables

Tags: string, python-3.x, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am facing an issue while I am trying to pass the join elements as variables in pyspark dataframe join function. I am getting primary key fields from a file while I am trying pass it as variable in a join statement, it throws an error as "cannot resolve the column name" since it is passed as a string. Please assist me on this.

```
for i in range(len(pr_list)):
    if i != len(pr_list)-1:
        pr_str += " (df_a." + pr_list[i] + " == df_b." +pr_list[i] +") & "
    else:
        pr_str += "(df_a." + pr_list[i]  + " == df_b." +pr_list[i]  +")"
print (pr_str)

df1_with_db2 = df_a.join(df_b, pr_str ,'inner').select('df_a.*')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By looking at your error it looks your `pr_list` can have columns which are neither present on any of 2 df or you didn't alias you `dataframes` befor joining like

```
df1_with_db2 = df_a.alias("df_a").join(df_b.alias("df_b"), pr_str ,'inner').select('df_a.*')
```

### Below is my way to do this problem:-

In your code, I found both `dataframe` have the same name of columns and that are in list `pr_list`

So you can just pass this list as join condition like below (by default join is `inner`):

```
df1_with_db2 = df_a.join(
            df_b, 
            pr_list
      )
```

### you will get common column only one time so no need to write select function

Here is a example:-

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    [1,2],
    [3,4],
    [9,8]
], ['a', 'b'])

df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    [1,2],
    [3,4],
    [18,19]
], ['a', 'b'])

jlist = ['a','b'] 

df1.join(df2, jlist).show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
+---+---+
```

Comment: @Jack welcome, read it again you will get more, i just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for showing this error is because in the join condition you are passing the join condition as string and in the join condition it accepts either a single column name or list of column names or condition with expressions, you just want to minor change in the code

```
df1_with_db2 = df_a.alias("df_a").join(df_b, eval(pr_str) ,'inner').select('df_a.*')
```